# Google mail filter for read messages

Tags: gmail

Let me describe my the filter I want to make:

When I receive an email from (for example user1@hotmail.com) onto my Google Mail account named (test@google.nl) I see the message in my inbox. Once I read the message I want to make a filter that **once read** it places the mail in the corresponding place.

I tried to make a filter but it sends the email straight to the corresponding label instead of when I read the email.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but filters only word on messages when they're received. They won't work on messages that you already have. Also, note that Gmail uses labels, not folders. A message can have multiple labels. "Inbox" is a special label, but it is just a label.

The workflow you're describing is exactly what the inbox and archiving is meant to do.

So, create your filter that matches your criteria and adds the label that you want. (But be sure *not* to choose the "Skip the Inbox" option.) Then...

1. When a new message comes in, it will be labeled with "inbox" as well as your custom label
2. Read the messages in your inbox. When you've read the message and are done with it, choose *Archive*. This will remove the "inbox" label but will leave any other custom labels intact.

The end result is you'll have custom labels on your messages, and the ones you still need to deal with will also be labelled with "inbox".

If you have a bunch of messages now that you've read and want to get out of your inbox, you can search for `is:read in:inbox label:{your-label}`, select all of the messages, and Archive them en masse.